# Installing xampp but phpmyadmin doesn't connect

Tags: mysql, xampp

So I installed xampp on my Linux machine running Ubuntu 14.04LTS. Now all of a sudden turns out when I try to connect to phpmyadmin it refuses to connect. I have already installed mysql separately as well but it doesn't seem to work. Any workaround for this?

The error that I get is :

```
MySQL said:
```

`Cannot connect: invalid settings. 
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.`

Any reason why this happens and solution to it?

Comment: Did you try use mysql client in command line for connection?
Did you [configure host, port, login and password in phpmyadmin](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config/Servers#host)?

Comment: 2 MYSQL Servers wont run on the same port (usually 3306) so you are likely connecting to the OTHER MySQL Server where either you userid does not exist or it has another password

Comment: Worked for me @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to http://localhost/security/ and then click on the link http://localhost/security/xamppsecurity.php.
2. After that change password for superuser to 'root'.

   After that open your http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment by [RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly) I was running two instances of MySQL

So both mysql servers do end up messing with phpmyadmin and this is how you shutdown the external mysql server while using xampp's inbuilt mysql server to connect successfully using phpmyadmin:

1. Use `whichmysql` to find the utility that is running
2. Navigate to the directory where the external MySQL service is running:

   `$ cd /usr/bin`

   `$ mysqladmin  shutdown`

This shuts down the MySQL service running if at all it is running.

```
$ sudo service mysql stop
```

This helps as well if at all it will tell you the status of the service if it is already shut down.

3. Now we need to stop the Xampp mysql server so we navigate to `/lampp/bin` and again execute the same command to shut mysql server down.

   `$ cd /opt/lampp/bin`

   `$ mysqladmin  shutdown`
4. Simply restart xampp and you should be good to go.

   `$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart`

Answer (score 0):

I just fell into the same error. The solution I used was, stopping all the servers of xampp, exiting the program. Starting and stoping mysql then starting xampp again
Initial procedure before starting xampp:

1. `sudo service mysql stop`
2. `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop`

If it bring the error as stated in this question, then follow the procedure below.
That is:

1. `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop`
2. `sudo service mysql start`
3. `sudo service mysql stop`
4. `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`